# How to loop and validate all values of a JSON message in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

In order to create a new records in my MongoDB database, I need to check if all fields of the received JSON message are defined (null, "", {} etc...). How can I do this in an easy and fast (generic) way?

**The database model:**

```
var measurementSchema = {  
    "initStamp": Date,
    "modStamp": Date,
    "protocol": Number,
    "engine": {
        "amp": Number,
        "volt": Number,
        "temp": Number,
        "pcbTemp": Number,
        "rpm": Number
    },
    "bms": {    
        "amp": Number,
        "volt": Number,
        "percent": Number,
        "ampHours": Number,
        "health": Number,
        "temp": Number,
        "lowVolt": Number,
        "highVolt": Number,
        "avgVolt": Number  
    },
    "mppt": [    {      
        "id": Number,
        "batteryFull": Boolean,
        "overheat": Boolean,
        "noCharge": Boolean,
        "lowVolt": Boolean,
        "volt": Number,
        "amps": Number,
        "batteryVolt": Number,
        "envTemp": Number    
    }  ],
    "gps": {    
        "gpsQuality": Number,
        "gpsTime": Date,
        "satellitesUsed": Number,
        "latitude": Number,
        "nsIndicator": String,
        "longitude": Number,
        "ewIndicator": String,
        "speed": Number,
        "accuracy": Number,
        "vector": {      
            "x": Number,
            "y": Number,
            "z": Number    
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: You want someone to write a function that returns false if at least one of the properties of measurementSchema is not defined ? Right ?

Comment: Do you just want to check that each property exists or that it is the correct type as well? e.g. Does the field `initStamp` need to just be defined or do you also want to check if it is of type Date?

Comment: Checking if property has a value is enough for my application...

Comment: is there a mistake ? the property  **mppt** is an Array of only one element!!! I advise you to not to setting it as an Array but rather as a sheer sub object

Comment: This code is taken from my documentation. In real there are 4 mppts, but it would make the documentation longer. Sorry for the confusion..

Comment: So even if the property is `null` or the empty string, it counts as defined in your use case? In that case, are you just wanting to check that the returned JSON has all expected properties and that one isn't missing? So engine should have 5 properties, each mppt has 9 properties, etc?

Comment: @StevenLambert No, I need to check if they are NOT null

Comment: So you only care that there are no properties that contain `null`, the empty string, or an empty array/object?

Comment: @StevenLambert Yep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this!

```
function isJSONValid(obj) {

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] !== null && obj[key] !== undefined) {
      if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
        if (Object.keys(obj[key]).length === 0) {
          return false; //invalid
        }
      }
      if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
        if (obj[key].length === 0) {
          return false; //invalid
        }
      }
      if (!isJSONValid(obj)) {
        return isJSONValid(obj);
      }

    } else {
      return false; //invalid
    }
  }
  return true; //valid
};

var canICreateNewRecords = isJSONValid(measurementSchema);
```

EDIT: better answer your specific conditions.

EDIT 2: move away from using typeof in the condition you encounter an array.

Comment: `typeof` never returns `"array"`

Comment: ah good catch... shoud use Array.isArray(obj[key]) instead... will edit

Comment: What happens with your code when I don't receive a "bms" object for example?

Comment: The function, given an object, would return false if it found any property of any object at any depth was null, an empty object, or empty array.  Otherwise it returns true.  It basically does a deep search of the object you give it for any of your "invalid" cases, and tells you whether or not the object given is valid.

Comment: Would it be helpful if I added some comments to the code block in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple way to check for null, empty strings, or empty arrays/objects is to stringify the JSON and check for values of `null`, `""`, and `{}` or `[]`.

```
var measurementSchema = {  
  "initStamp": null,
  "engine": {
    "amp": "",
  },
   "mppt": [{}]
};

/""|null|\{\}|\[\]/g.test(JSON.stringify(measurementSchema))  //=> true - a property is not defined
```

Comment: Would it be possible to output the empty fields using this code?

Comment: As in, the name of the field that is empty? Best you can do is this regex, but it has its limitations depending on nested values `"(\w+)":[\{\[]*(?:""|null|\{\}|\[\])`